# Prolog singleton variables in rule head causes program to output booleans for all queries

Tags: prolog

I have this prolog program.

```pl
red(rose).
red(anthurium).

white(rose).
white(gardenia).
white(jasmine).

like(Y,X) :-
  red(X),!,
  fail
  ;
  white(X).
```

And below is how it responds to different queries.

```pl
?- like(rose,gardenia).
true.

?- like(rose,P).
false.

?- like(Val,anthurium).
false.

?- like(rose,X).
false
```

The problem I now have is this:

When querying with a variable within the query (Eg: `?- like(rose,X).`), Prolog usually responds by returning a value, (something like `X=some_val`). Why I don't get any value for those variables, but either `true` or `false`?

All helpful answers are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what Prolog is doing here:

`like(rose,P)` succeeds if `red(P)`, so it grabs a possible substitution for `P`, namely `rose` or `anthurium`. Then it traverses the `cut` and then it `fail`s. But "failing" means that the proof search down that path didn't bring any solution, there are no successful bindings to report (the only fail to get information out of a failing branch is to side-effect to a log file and read check it later). In fact, all bindings will be undone on backtracking. The second branch is `white(X)`, but `rose` is not white, so we fail here, too.

You can also write:

```
like(_,X) :- \+ red(X).
like(_,X) :- white(X).
```

which is a bit more readable. One notices that when calling `like(_,X)`, the goal enclosed by the negation-as-failure operator `\+` is nonground. This is bad, and causes a *floundering query* (in other words, don't do that). I have written this little page on ["floundering"](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/other_notes/about_negation/floundering.md).